# Create a selection tool in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

Hi i am developing a printing tool where user can draw and edit the shapes. I have developed the tools to draw shapes but i am not getting any idea how to develop a selection tool where user can select multiple objects and can edit them. If anyone have the solution so please help me to develop this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [this transform tool](http://www.senocular.com/?id=1.371) from senocular.com which seems to have served all my purposes so far.

You selectively pick which features to use & the code is relatively simple to tweak.

Besides there is a [demo](http://www.senocular.com/demo/TransformToolAS3/TransformTool.html) as well, using the same.

Comment: Thank you loxxy i got lot of help from it.